# Using SVG Icon causes Module parse failed: Unexpected keyword 'var'

Tags: reactjs, svg

Okay so I'm using a basic svg icon in my sidebar and out of 3 icons used, only this one is causing the error for some reason. It works fine in dev mode, so `npm start` works, but when I try to build it, it fails. So I create a component to return svg like

**exclamationpointicon.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const ExclamationPointIcon = () => (
    <svg width="20" height="20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
            d="M10 6.889V10m0 3.111h.008M17 10a7 7 0 1 1-14 0 7 7 0 0 1 14 0Z"
            stroke="#EF4444"
            strokeWidth="1.67"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
    </svg>
);

export { ExclamationPointIcon };
```

I import it

**sidebar.js**

```
import {
    SidebarSignoutIcon,
    CircledArrowIcon,
    ExclamationPointIcon,
} from 'components/Icons';
```

And I just use it

sidebar.js

```
{someCondition && !someOther ? (
  <Wrapper>
    <ExclamationPointIcon />
    <p>Enter ID</p>
  </Wrapper>
 ) : null}
```

The error is referencing line 29 inside sidebar which is a styled component line:

```
padding: 0;
```

Here's the full error text

```
ERROR in ./app/components/SideBar/index.js 29:69
Module parse failed: Unexpected keyword 'var' (29:69)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import styled from 'styled-components';
| import { ButtonReset } from 'components/Styled';
> import { SidebarSignoutIcon, CircledArrowIcon, ExclamationPointIcon, var _ref2 =
| /*#__PURE__*/
| _jsx(Wrapper, {}, void 0, _jsx(ExclamationPointIcon, {}), _jsx("p", {}, void 0, "Enter ID")); } from 'components/Icons';
 @ ./app/containers/App/index.js 62:0-41 373:64-71
 @ ./app/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js ./app/app.js
```

If I remove the `<ExclamationPointIcon />` line it works just fine, but this doesn't make any sense since the same file is using two more icons that are created/imported in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
export { ExclamationPointIcon }; // exclamationpointicon.js
import { ExclamationPointIcon } from 'components/Icons'; //sidebar.js
```

Try:

```
export default ExclamationPointIcon;
import ExclamationPointIcon from 'components/Icons/exclamationpointicon';
```